# how to handle wandb Invalid filename characters exception on uploading image

Tags: wandb

I am using windows 10 & venv & python 3.9.7
this is my code to upload image to wandb

```
wandb_log["Image/train_image"] = wandb.Image('tmp.jpg')
wandb.log(wandb_log, step)
```

the full directory of image is “C:\Users\이준혁\Documents\Github\terenz\tmp.jpg”
However it creates this error

```
Media Image/train_image is invalid. Please remove invalid filename characters
```

reinstalling wandb did not help to solve this problem.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you try chaning the name from "Image/train_image" to something that doesn't involve "/". This seems like a windows specific issue. I guess changing the name will fix the problem.

Comment: @AyushChaurasia you were right. thanks